# Unicode Encode Error while using mechanize to log in to website

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, mechanize

I am using mechanize to log into website https://www.patientslikeme.com but I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2713' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128).
```

Please reply how can this be resolved.

Code:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots( False )

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

br.open('https://www.patientslikeme.com/users/sign_in')
br.select_form( nr=1)

br['user[email_or_login]'] = 'divyat'
br['user[password]']= 'nothing'

logged_in= br.submit()
logincheck= logged_in.read()
```

Error is caused by the line `logged_in= br.submit()`

Comment: What line of your code causes the error?

Comment: John Gordon thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure `br['user[email_or_login]'] = 'divyat'` is the right way to fill in form fields?  All the tutorials I have seen do it this way: `br.form['field'] = value`

Comment: I have tried using br.form['field'] = value too but it still leads to the same error.